# How do I implement a datatype, like a stack, in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I need to implement a custom data structure in assembly. Preferably, it needs to be dynamic. Something like a linked list in C++/Java where each element points to the next element. Please note that the size of each element may vary.

How can I do this?

Comment: "where each element points to the next element" -> Do you mean linked list?

Comment: how about writing it in C, compile and look and generated code ?

Comment: umm yeah i meant a linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same you would in C. Assembly has functions and address spaces. Start with the basics: what functions does your stack need to have? Put the actual datastructures aside and focus on the big picture.

All you need is a function to push() and a function to pop(), a place to stick these items in the memory, and a counter to tell you how much of that space you've used up.

Oh, you should probably review your data structures before starting, as in neither C++ nor Java (or any other language, as a matter of fact) does an object pushed onto a stack point to the next object on the stack. That's called a linked list.

Comment: Yup i meant a linked list. Sorry I was in a hurry to type this question. And no, it is not as simple as a linked list/stack. otherwise id have just asked about that. I just want to get some basic idea about the data structures so that i can go about creating the data structure that i need on my own.

Comment: I got what you meant by referring to C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing your data structure using C and then look at the assembly generated.  For your memory needs, however, it might require some more careful considerations (such as using non-volatile vs. volatile memory for storage for the varying sized elements).